# Soldering capacitor pins

Tags: capacitor, soldering

When soldering capacitors, is the order on which you solder them important?

I am about to solder a project but I don't know this information

For example, I can solder each pin however I like, or one pin is goes somewhere, the other elsewhere?

Noob question, but first time soldering capacitors.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion. Have you soldered something else where it did matter what order you soldered in? The usual example is many-pin devices where we might solder opposite corners first. Was their something specific that caused you to be concerned?

Comment: @gbulmer: of course, soldering opposite corners is to make the job easier, not because you are required to.

Comment: Corner comment: For through hole ICs (not SMD). Solder one corner with pressure on IC if possible to seat onto PCB.  Solder 2nd corner as for corner 1. THEN apply seating pressure to IC and reflow (melt and let cool) first corner again. IC will often click home with a satisfying audible 'snick'. Redo 2nd corner likewise.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are talking about component orientation, not literally the order of soldering the wires.  In this case, yes for some capacitors it is important which way around they go.  The negative lead is identified with a "-" or  a stripe down the side.  The positive lead may be longer.

This is a typical electrolytic capacitor, showing the stripe and the line of "-" signs that identify the negative lead.

[image: Capacitor]

For ceramic capacitors (usually orange discs) it doesn't matter which way around they go.

Comment: Orange disks? I haven't seen orange disks in ages. All my ceramics are little tan rectangles with no &^%$#@! markings on them!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no power should be applied to a board you are soldering to so pin order does not matter. If they are polarized capacitors just make sure you don't solder the leads in backwards.